# Pandas column - convert string to Shapely point using map() function

Tags: python, pandas, shapely

I have a dataset of observations which contain (latitude, longitude) data as strings in the following format:
`'POINT (30.6280359000000004 -96.3051219999999972)'`
`'POINT (40.7815247999999997 -74.0058204000000046)'`

I am trying to parse these strings as Shapely points so they can be used in a GeoPandas dataframe. I've written a simple function to parse the strings: `parse_point`. This works fine on a single test string made from a single record in the Pandas column to be operated on,'GeoTagStart'. However, the map function is giving an error - list index out of range, see below. By using print as the code is executing, I can see that the pandas map() function below is treating the column like a single array or list, whereas I had understood that the map() function over a Pandas column works row-by-row. Any ideas where I am going wrong please and how to make this work? It's probably something simple, but I can't see it. 
Thanks!

```
from shapely.geometry import Point

def parse_point(record):
    pieces = record.split() # splits each record into a list of 3
    x = float(pieces[1].lstrip('(')) # latitude
    y = float(pieces[2].rstrip(')')) # longitude 
    point = Point(x,y) # convert to Shapely Point
    return point

test1 = df['GeoTagStart'][3]
test2 = df['GeoTagStart'][50]    

print(parse_point(test1))
assert type(parse_point(test1)) == Point # this works fine, returns  shapely.geometry.point.Point

print(parse_point(test2))
assert type(parse_point(test2)) == Point # this works fine

df['new_col'] = df['momGeoTagStart'].map(lambda x: parse_point(x)) # this throws an error: 

<ipython-input-5-92a2b4f58255> in <lambda>(x)
     24 assert type(parse_point(test2)) == Point
     25 
---> 26 df['new_col'] = df['GeoTagStart'].map(lambda x: parse_point(x))
     27 

<ipython-input-5-92a2b4f58255> in parse_point(record)
     13 def parse_point(record):
     14     pieces = record.split()
---> 15     x = float(pieces[1].lstrip('('))
     16     y = float(pieces[2].rstrip(')'))
     17     point = Point(x,y)

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: In my opinion error means `pieces = record.split()` return not list with length 3, but empty or list with length 1 or 2. So data problem.

Comment: You definitely have some missing data or just data that doesn't correspond to you pattern. Check it.

Comment: And you can check it by `print (df[df['GeoTagStart'].str.len() != 3])`

Comment: OK, thank you very much for looking - I will give this a go and report back ...

Comment: Problem solved - a combination of a couple of rogue data points having extra characters deep in the file, and some being NaN. Thanks for your help!